# How to set TextField width according to stage width? Actionscript 3, as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can anyone tell me how to dynamically adjust the *width* of a *TextField* so that it's always a little less than the width of the stage? For example, this is what I've tried, but it raises an error:

```
var myText:TextField = new TextField();
    myText.x = 20; 
    myText.width = stage.stageWidth - 40; //does not work, what

stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, adjustTextField);

function adjustTextField():void
{
    myText.x = 20; 
    myText.width = stage.stageWidth - 40;
}
```

In theory this code should ensure that *myText* is always adjusting to the full width of the stage with a 20 pixel border on both sides. But, this raises an error.

Does anyone know a way to get fluid widths on TextFields in **Actionscript 3**?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: I've tried Googling that error already, can't find anything that has helped yet. Not sure what why the stage width of would be considered a null object reference.

Comment: try `trace(stage.width);` and see what it prints.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a reference to `stage` yet. Whatever class this code is in, `stage` will be null until the instance has been added to the display list (eg. via `addChild`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something with stage when myText is added to stage

```
var myText:TextField = new TextField();
myText.x = 20;
this.addChild(myText);//add myText to some parent
myText.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddToStage);

private function onAddToStage(event:Event):void {

    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, adjustTextField);
}
```